# Problems with calling a JS function

Tags: javascript

I have a function which populates a div but includes js onclick. How ever its producing some weird error i've not seen before.

This is the function:

```
//Browser Support Code for AJAX Requests
function ajaxFunction(url,data){
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {              
    AJAX=new XMLHttpRequest();              
  } else {                                  
    AJAX=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  if (AJAX) {
  querystring = "?dta="+data;
     AJAX.open("GET", url + querystring, false);                             
     AJAX.send(null);
     return AJAX.responseText;                                         
  } else {
     return false;
  }                                             
}       


function subpopulate(id,array,type){ alert('test2'); // alert to check if called
document.getElementById(id).innerHTML += "<div class='subm'>test</div>";
}

function menu(type,scri,get){ alert('test'); //alert to check if called
        var result = ajaxFunction(scri,get);
        subpopulate('offset',result,type);
}

function loadmain(id){
document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = "<table style='width:100%;'><tr><td><a href='#' onclick='javascript:menu('build','build.php','false');'>Build</a></td></tr></table>";
}
```

When i click the link it doesn't call "menu" function it errors with this:

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }

In console errors all I see is for its information is this below:

```
 window.script1332821403739=1;
```

Any ideas why this is happening :S ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace onclick event code in loadmain method as following:

```
onclick='javascript:menu(\"build\",\"build.php\",\"false\");'
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the single quotes within your javascript code you have embedded in your HTML table tag.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
onclick='javascript:menu('build','build.php','false');'
```

to

```
onclick='javascript:menu(\'build\',\'build.php\',\'false\');'
```